# Does lots of empty/boilerplate classes (Exceptions, Events) significantly impact Android performance/size?

Tags: java, android, boilerplate

It seems common in java to use completely empty classes just so you can use method overloading, etc.

e.g.

```
public class EventA {}
public class EventB {}
public class EventC {}
```

then somewhere

```
public handleEvent(EventA e) {
 // do something
}

public handleEvent(EventB e) {
 // do something else
}
```

etc.

I've seen it advised to avoid enums in Android, and instead to use `public static final int`s.

Would it be a worthwhile optimization (perhaps at the expense of some readability) to just have

```
public class GenericEvent {
  public static final int A = 0;
  public static final int B = 1;
  public static final int C = 2;

  public final int whichEvent;

  public GenericEvent(final int whichEvent) {
    this.whichEvent = whichEvent;
  }
}
```

And then have

```
public handleEvent(GenericEvent e) {
  switch(e.whichEvent) {
    case GenericEvent.A:
      // do something
    case GenericEvent.B:
      // do something else
```

etc.

In this example we only have 3 events (A, B, C) but in practice this could be 30+.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all 'Premature optimization is the root of all evil' ;)

In my opinion working with int id's is not bad.

If you design your handlers a different way, the code become even more readable.

For example:

```
private static class Example{
    public static final int A = 0;
    public static final int B = 1;
    public static final int C = 2;
    final private SparseArray<Event> mRegisteredEvents=new SparseArray<>(10);
    public interface Event{
        void call();
    }

    public Example() {
        registerEvent(A, new Event() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                Log.d("TAG", "event a");
            }
        });
    }


    public void registerEvent(int id,Event event){
        mRegisteredEvents.put(id,event);
    }

    public void handleEvent(int id){
        mRegisteredEvents.get(id).call();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, in both cases you create an object, pass it around and make it eligible for garbage collector. The only difference is that classloader has a bit more work to do dealing with that bunch of classes. Naturally, it adds some overhead but barely enough to worry about.

1. Classes are loaded dynamically, on a need basis. Only the classes your app actually uses will be loaded.
2. In terms of memory, when loaded, every class will cost you as much as a single `java.lang.Class` object on the heap.
3. Class loading is not that expensive under normal circumstances. You may read some [specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) if you're interested.

With your second approach you would gain some ephemeral performance improvement at the expense of flexibility. What happens if you want to pass some event-specific data at later point?

Either way, questions like yours are best answered with a simple benchmark. But I bet there are always better candidates for a bottleneck in your app.